# Primefaces JS Inserted before other resources causing error

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces, colorbox

I'm using JSF2.0 and Eclipse Indigo, and just recently I added the PrimeFaces library to my build path. Before this I had a "lightbox" working by using jquery1.7.2 + colorbox. I had the following includes:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" type="text/css"/>  
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="colorbox.css" type="text/css"/>        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.colorbox.js" target="head"/>
```

The resources are located in `WebContent/resources/js`.

After adding *PrimeFaces* my "lightbox" no longer worked, because the `colorbox` function was not found. After looking at the source that JSF2 was generating, I noticed that the library inserted it's own version of jQuery above my `jquery.colorbox.js` so that the colorbox library couldn't use the jQuery library. Furthermore, the jquery.colorbox.js include was missing.

How do I relocate the PrimeFaces JavaScript libraries to a different location on the page? How come my `jquery.colorbox.js` isn't loading as it was previously?

My actual page might be useful. It is [here](https://github.com/knownasilya/Ambience/blob/master/g5.ambience/WebContent/index.xhtml).

I still get the same error from the JavaScript console in Chrome.
I get this when the page loads:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

And the following when I click my *colorbox* link:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorbox'
(anonymous function):8080/g5.ambience/:24
b.event.dispatchjquery.js.html:16
b.event.add.bD.handle.bB
```

Even with Daniels suggestions, here is the source that is produced: http://pastie.org/3851179

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) try using primefaces bundled jquery (3.2 version uses the 1.7.1 jQuery)

replace the

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript target="head">
    $ = jQuery;
</h:outputScript>
```

**EDIT**

2) another option is to load your jQuery and the colorbox plugin before the loading of the primefaces bundled jQuery (not tested and not even sure that it will work , so it's not recommended :) )

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
    <h:outputScript target="head">
        $ = jQuery;
    </h:outputScript>
</f:facet>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.colorbox.js" target="head"/>
```

Comment: When I added the library to my build path, it automatically injects the PrimeFaces jquery.js. I tried removing my jquery.js include and seeing if my colorbox was working. Unfortunately it did not help. The problem is that `jquery.colorbox.js` has stopped showing up, even though I have the `<h:outputScript>` tag and it was working before I included PrimeFaces in my build path.

Comment: I'll give it a try once I'm at my workstation :) If it works I'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: b.t.w what primefaces version do you use?

Comment: I'm using PrimeFaces v3.2; the latest release.

Comment: No luck. `colorbox` does show up now, but still doesn't work.

Comment: what js errors do you see in the firebug / browser dev tools ?

Comment: **Edit2** in my original post has the JS errors.

Comment: look at my EDIT , try it (the error you see caused because the jquery.colorbox.js loads before the jquery itself...)

Comment: Thanks! Putting the `<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.colorbox.js" target="head"/>` after the `<f:facet></f:facet>` tag worked! Accepted!